# Connection to Redis through SSH tunnel: reset by peer

Tags: ssh, redis, connection, tunnel

My Redis instance is installed and run at `VIRTUAL_MACHINE`. I connect to `VIRTUAL_MACHINE` via SSH tunnel through `TUNNEL_SERVER` to work from my local machine.

Tunnel string is the following:

`ssh -L 0.0.0.0:10011:VIRTUAL_MACHINE:22 -L 0.0.0.0:10004:VIRTUAL_MACHINE:6379 -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -o ServerAliveInterval=15 -o ServerAliveCountMax=3 username@TUNNEL_SERVER`

The issue is I can't connect to Redis instance from the local machine:

`redis-cli -h 0.0.0.0 -p 10004`
`0.0.0.0:10004> ping`
`Error: Connection reset by peer`

`telnet 0.0.0.0 10004`
`Trying 0.0.0.0...`
`Connected to 0.0.0.0.`
`Escape character is '^]'.`
`Connection closed by foreign host.`

On the remote machine (`VIRTUAL MACHINE`):

`redis-cli -h localhost -p 6379`
`localhost:6379> ping`
`PONG`

`netstat -an | grep 6379`
`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6379            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`

**redis.conf**

- bind 127.0.0.1
- bind 0.0.0.0
- protected-mode no
- port 6379
- timeout 60
- tcp-keepalive 600
- daemonize no

Because of Redis, I can't also connect to Flower (Celery).

If you have any idea about possible reasons, please help me to figure it out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Only just saw this,

- Can you SSH to 0.0.0.0:10011 and have access to the VIRTUAL_MACHINE?
- Also are your auth creds for the TUNNEL_SERVER the same as for the   VIRTUAL_MACHINE?

Forgive me if you already have, but, I would get SSH working to the VIRTUAL_MACHINE first via the TUNNEL_SERVER and then rework that to tunnel REDIS